# How to get the longest string in a set of strings in c++

Tags: c++11, set

I have a set of strings

```
set<string> strings;
```

How do I get the longest string contained in the set? In python I could do the following:

```
print max(strings, key=len)
```

Is there a similar function in c++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) that ships with the `<algorithm>` header and pass a custom comparison predicate.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

const auto longest = std::max_element(strings.cbegin(), strings.cend(),
    [](const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs) { return lhs.size() < rhs.size(); });

if (longest != strings.cend())
    std::cout << *longest << "\n";
```

This is clearly not as concise as the python version, and this is where ranges are to the rescue. With [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/) projections, this boils down to

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

const auto longest = ranges::max_element(strings, std::less<>{}, &std::string::size);
```